# How to load a angularjs controller's templateUrl into a jasmine test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and jasmine, so this is probably a simple one.  However, I am having trouble accessing the HTML template from the jasmine test.  I create the controller with a beforeEach.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('yeomanApp'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('yeomanApp.services'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $routeParams, 
        _$httpBackend_,  $window, ) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    routeParams = $routeParams;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    window = $window;

    SampleCtrl = $controller ('SampleCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $routeParams: routeParams,
        $http: httpBackend,
        $window: window
    });

}));
```

However, I can not access the form from jasmine, it appear my HTML, does not have any forms.  I than call a test such as:

```
it('submit form in HTML.', function () {
        console.log("%O", window.document.forms);
...
});
```

My form is not there.  Further, the HTML in the document is some default karma stuff.

Clearly, I am missing a step.  I need to define my HTML template somewhere, I assume/hope.